# Embed video through Tag Manager HTML Tag

Tags: html, iframe, google-tag-manager

Basically the title. I would like to know if its posible to embed a youtube video using HTML tag from tag manager side. When i try just copy&paste the iframe i get an error.

> Invalid HTML, CSS, or JavaScript found in template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone need to do this i manage to make it work with a custom js variable:

[image: js]

I used a constant for the link so it can be changed fast and finally a HTML tag:

[image: html]

Hope someone find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use JS custom variable for any actions, except getting data from HTML DOM, because GTM is executing JS variable many times during page load (after each mouse click)

The correct way to do that is to do that in your tag:
[image]